# FluentValidation - Check value is an expression only if the value is not null

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

I am trying to Validate that a Cron Expression is valid only when the property is not null

My code looks like this,

```
 RuleFor(team => team.PlayTimeSlot)
                .Must(IsValidSchedule)
                .When(team => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(team.PlayTimeSlot));

 public bool IsValidSchedule(string schedule)
        {
        // Some Schedule validation logic
        }
```

However this does not work. What am I missing ?

Comment: this code works well for me. Could you please show us how do you test it? Maybe you need `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace`?

Comment: @RomanMarusyk the problem is the property is a nullable string while the method only accepts string. Since the method is calling a thirdparty dll, I cant change its signature

Comment: it would be great if you add it to the question because the code looks good

Answer (score 0):

I would try to separate everything into methods as an alternative like this:

```
RuleFor(team => team.PlayTimeSlot)
        .When(playTimeValid)
        .Must(IsValidSchedule);

public bool isValidSchedule()
{
    return true
}
public bool playTimeValid(TeamModel team)
{
    if !string.isnullorempty(team.playtimeslot)
    return true
}
```

Can you Try that with your code?

Comment: but how does it solve the issue? This is the same